# How can I have an admin controller in Magento and use it in phhtml for uploading file

Tags: php, plugins, magento2

I'm beginner in PHP and Magento,
I have Plugin which has a admin menu which refers to a page.
What I want to do is adding an admin controller for uploading a file to server from the page.
this is my structure:

- MyPlugin/KnownUser/Controller/Adminhtml/Admin/Index.php

  ```
  <?php
  namespace MyPlugin\KnownUser\Controller\Adminhtml\Admin;
  require_once( __DIR__ .'../../../../IntegrationInfoProvider.php');
  use \DateTime;

    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
      /**
      * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
      */
      protected $resultPageFactory;
      public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) 
  {

       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

  }

  public function execute()
  {           
      $configProvider = new \MyPlugin\KnownUser\IntegrationInfoProvider();
      $configText =  $configProvider->getIntegrationInfo(true);
      $customerIntegration = json_decode($configText, true);

      $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
      $layout = $resultPage->getLayout();
      $block = $layout->getBlock('main_panel');
      $block->setAccountId($customerIntegration["AccountId"]);
      $block->setVersion($customerIntegration["Version"]);
      $block->setPublishDate($customerIntegration["PublishDate"]);
      $block->setUploadUrl($this->getUrl('knownuser/admin/process/index'));   
      $block->setIntegrationConfig( $configText);
      return $resultPage;

  }   

  }
  ```

  - MyPlugin\knownuser\view\adminhtml\templates\admin.phtml

```html
      <p>
          <label style="width:200px">Publisher</label>
          <br />
          <input readonly type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getAccountId() ?>"> </input>
      </p>
      <p>
          <label style="width:100px">Version</label>
          <br />
          <input readonly type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getVersion() ?>">
          </input>
      </p>
      <p>
          <label style="width:100px">Publish Date</label>
          <br />
          <input readonly type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getPublishDate() ?
          >" > </input>
      </p>
      <p>
          <label style="width:100px">IntegrationdedConfig</label>
      </p>
      
      <textarea rows="10" cols="200" readonly>
      <?php echo $this->getIntegrationConfig() ?>
            </textarea>
      
      <form id='form' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
          <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
      </form>
      <script>
      
          const url = '<?php echo $this->getUploadUrl()?>';
          alert(url);
          const form = document.getElementById('form');
      
          form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
              const formData = new FormData();
      
              for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                  let file = files[i];
      
                  formData.append('files[]', file);
              }
              debugger;
              fetch(url, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: formData
              }).then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
              });
          });
      </script>
```

So what I want to do is add a new controller and post my file to server, but I don't know how can I do that.
I tried to add another controller and post my file from JavaScript but it didn't work and just redirect my request.
my controller is like this:

- MyPlugin\knownuser\Controller\Adminhtml\Process

  ```
    <?php
    namespace MyPlugin\KnownUser\Controller\Adminhtml\Admin;
    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
       public function execute()
      {           

         die('test index');
         echo('just for sure it has been ran');
      }   

    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, I just needed to add another controller like this and use it in my html:

```
<?php

namespace Queueit\KnownUser\Controller\Adminhtml\Admin;

class UploadConfig extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

public function execute()
{
    $configProvider = new \Queueit\KnownUser\IntegrationInfoProvider();
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        print_r('{');
            $errors = "";
            $extensions = ['json'];
            $uploads = new \Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
            $files  = $uploads->getFileInfo();

            $file_name= '';

            $file_tmp ='';
            foreach ($files as $file => $fileInfo) {
                if ($uploads->isUploaded($file)) {
                    if ($uploads->isValid($file)) {
                        if ($uploads->receive($file)) {
                            $info = $uploads->getFileInfo($file);
                            $file_name = $info[$file]['name'];
                            $file_type = $info[$file]['type'];
                            $file_tmp  = $info[$file]['tmp_name'];

                            $file_ext1 = explode('.', $file_name);
                            $file_ext2 = end($file_ext1);
                            $file_ext = strtolower($file_ext2);

                            if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
                                $errors = 'extension not allowed: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            $strConfig = "";
            if ($file_name != "") {

                if ($errors == "") {
                    $strConfig = file_get_contents($file_tmp);
                    $objectConfig = json_decode($strConfig);
                    $configProvider->updateIntegrationInfo($objectConfig->integrationInfo, $objectConfig->hash);
                    print_r("\"stat\" : \"Successful\",");
                    $configText =  $configProvider->getIntegrationInfo(false);
                    print_r("\"configText\" : " . $configText);
                }
            } else {
                $errors = 'Config file is not found in your request!';
            }

            if ($errors) {
                print_r("\"errors\" : \"");
                print_r($errors);
                print_r("\"");
            }
        print_r('}');
    }
  }
 }
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
     <p>
         <label style="width:200px">Publisher: </label>
         <label id="AccountId"><?php echo $this->getAccountId() ?></label>
     </p>
     <p>
         <label style="width:100px">Version: </label>

         <label id="Version"><?php echo $this->getVersion() ?> </label>
     </p>
     <p>
         <label style="width:100px">Publish Date: </label>

         <label id="PublishDate" class="form-control"> <?php echo $this->getPublishDate() ?> </label>
     </p>
     <button id='asdf' class="collapsible">Display JSON Integration Configuration</button>
     <div class="content">         
         <div id="Config">

         </div>
     </div>

 </div>

 <hr class="HR_1" />
 <div> <span>Select your new Integration Configuration to update the old one:</span></div>
 <br />
 <div style="overflow: auto">
     <form id='form' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <label class="button" style="float:left">
             <input type="file" name="files[]" accept=".json" id="files[]" class="button">
             <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Select configuration:
         </label> <input type='text' id="upload-file-name" class="input-text" style='margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 4px;width:400px;float:left'>
         <button id="submit-uplode-file" class="button" type="submit" disabled name="submit" style="float:left">
             <span id="SPAN_3">Update Configuration</span>
         </button>
     </form>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div id="announcement"></div>

 <script>
         require([
        'jquery'], function ($) {
     
     var configString = '<?php echo $this->getIntegrationConfig() ?>';
    if (configString != '') {
        var config = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(configString), null, '\t');
    }

     function output(inp) {
         var configNode = document.getElementById("Config");
         while (configNode.firstChild) {
             configNode.removeChild(configNode.firstChild);
         }
         configNode.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
     }

     function syntaxHighlight(json) {
         json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
         return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function(match) {
             var cls = 'number';
             if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                 if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                     cls = 'key';
                 } else {
                     cls = 'string';
                 }
             } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                 cls = 'boolean';
             } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                 cls = 'null';
             }
             return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
         });
     }
     (function() {
   if (config) {
         output(syntaxHighlight(config));
   }
         var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
         var i;

         for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
             coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                 this.classList.toggle("active");
                 var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                 if (content.style.display === "block") {
                     content.style.display = "none";
                 } else {
                     content.style.display = "block";
                 }
             });
         }

         const url = '<?php echo $this->getUploadUrl() ?>';
         document.getElementById('files[]').onchange = function(e) {
             if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
                 var filename = e.target.files[0].name;
                 document.getElementById("upload-file-name").value = filename;
                 document.getElementById("announcement").innerHTML = '';
                 document.getElementById("submit-uplode-file").disabled = false;
             }
         };

         const form = document.getElementById('form');

         form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
             e.preventDefault();        
             const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
             const formData = new FormData();

             for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                 let file = files[i];

                 formData.append('files[]', file);
             }

             console.log(files);
             jQuery.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 type: "POST",
                 data: formData,
                 contentType: false,
                 cache: false,
                 processData: false,
                 beforeSend: function() {
                     console.log('Sending');
                 },
                 success: function(data) {                  
                     console.log(data);

                     try {
                         var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                     } catch (e) {
                         jQuery("#announcement").html("<Span style='color:red'>" + "Some thing went wrong!" + "</Span>").fadeIn();
                         jQuery("#announcement").html("<Span style='color:red'>" + data + "</Span>").fadeIn();
                     }
                     if (jsonData.stat != undefined && jsonData.stat == 'Successful') {
                         jQuery("#AccountId").text(jsonData.configText.AccountId);
                         jQuery("#PublishDate").text(jsonData.configText.PublishDate);
                         jQuery("#Version").text(jsonData.configText.Version);
                         output(syntaxHighlight(JSON.stringify(jsonData.configText, null, '\t')));
                         //  jQuery("#Config").text(JSON.stringify(jsonData.configText, null, '\t'));


                         jQuery("#announcement").html("<Span style='color:#4CAF50'>The File is uploaded successfully!</Span>").fadeIn();
                         document.getElementById("submit-uplode-file").disabled = true;
                     } else {
                         if (jsonData.errors != undefined && jsonData.errors != '') {
                             jQuery("#announcement").html("<Span style='color:red'>" + jsonData.errors + "</Span>").fadeIn();
                         } else {

                             jQuery("#announcement").html("<Span style='color:red'>" + "Some thing went wrong!" + "</Span>").fadeIn();

                         }
                     }
                 },
                 error: function(e) {
                     console.log(e);
                     jQuery("#announcement").html("Uploading file is faild!").fadeIn();
                 }
             });
         });
     })();
        });
 </script>
```